# Length units different when compiling in Mac OSX vs Windows 10

Tags: spacing

When I use `\vskip`, `\vspace`, `\hspace` etc, and I use any of the spacing units for these commands: cm, em, in, pt...

I get two different results when running it on a Mac OSX vs. on a Windows 10 machine.

What I am doing is I have a file in a Dropbox folder and compiling them in the different machines I get different results. I am compiling the exact same code in both machines. For instance, if I write some text then I use `\vspace{1em}` and compile it on Windows, I get it approximately a half an inch down the page. Now if I compile the exact same document on my Mac I get the writing almost 1 inch down. This is quite a substantial difference. If anyone knows how to help me fix this, I would greatly appreciate it!

File list from .log for MAC: [dropbox.com/s/eb41l58tkjiu7ri/macOSX_filelist.txt?dl=0](https://dropbox.com/s/eb41l58tkjiu7ri/macOSX_filelist.txt?dl=0) Windows: [dropbox.com/s/g9r1xap3qz0qqth/windows_filelist.txt?dl=0](https://dropbox.com/s/g9r1xap3qz0qqth/windows_filelist.txt?dl=0)

Comment: To add to that, I updated both TeX Live versions by running the respective tlmgr updates on both machines.

Comment: So can you post a minimal document that replicates the result, including the contents after `**File List**` in your `.log` (from both machines) when you add `\listfiles` to the preamble?

Comment: tex will give identical space (on the same input)  but your pdf generation (or viewer) may be defaulting to A4 in one and US letter in the other

Comment: Is the paper size default set differently for the 2 installations? `tlmgr paper` will show you the defaults for the various formats.

Comment: Yes, I just checked both paper sizes and they are the same for all of the formats in both computers. They are all set to 'letter'. When I call document class and geometry I also define them as 'letterpaper' in the options.

Comment: File list from .log for MAC: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/eb41l58tkjiu7ri/macOSX_filelist.txt?dl=0] Windows: [https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9r1xap3qz0qqth/windows_filelist.txt?dl=0]

Comment: @MCF57 how exactly are you verifying this? This is a point that often comes up, the normal reason is the previewer that you use to view the PDF, some of them may actually scale the doc when printing. Can you make the PDF available?

Comment: @daleif, I am verifying this during the print and when I visualize it using TexStudio. The difference is significant and isn't a visual artifact of the reader. I will post the two different PDF's once I get back to my office.